Constant symbols in Sequent Calculus
My text book on Sequent Calculus gives the rule of inference for $\forall$ in the succedent as follows:
$$
\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow \Delta, \varphi(a)}{\Gamma \Rightarrow \Delta,\forall x \varphi(x)}\forall R
$$
Stating that "In ∀R, $a$ is a constant
symbol which must not occur anywhere in the lower sequent of the ∀R rule.
We call $a$ the eigenvariable of the ∀R inference."
Does that mean, that e.g. in the language of Peano arithmetic which has only one constant symbol $0$, my only choice for $a$ is $0$?
In the language of ZF which has no constant symbols, what can I use for $a$?

$a$ stands for a variable, not a constant symbol.

@NaïmFavier Should it say then "In ∀R, a is a VARIABLE symbol which must not occur FREE anywhere in the lower sequent of the ∀R rule." Would that be correct?

Yes, that's essentially what you want.

In some literature, we assume there are infinitely many constant symbols for us to use in this rule. They are essentially just free variables, and the wording is confusing.

Yes, the literature is notoriously confused about variables, and this leads to absurdities such as "there is no empty model" because, well, you need something to interpret those infinite constants. A modern treatment of logic should clearly keep track of variable scopes and not give meaning to free variables in an empty context.

Symbol $a$ stands for a free variable (or parameter) that must be “fresh” in the sense of having no other occurrences in $\Gamma , \Delta$.
The proviso is needed in order to avoid fallacious conclusions.
Using the basic rule, we can derive a rule that uses constants: see van Dalen, page 95: "If [constant] $c$ does not occur in $\Gamma$, then if $\Gamma \vdash \phi (c)$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \phi (x)$".
